# UNIQUE in Time fields (Avoid concurrent time)

Tags: php, database, time, unique

I want to make a website that users can register for classes.
the rule is that one user can't register in one class that is concurrent with registered classes.
how can I implement it?
Is is solvable in query? or php code?

Comment: Make an attempt.  See if it works.  If it doesn't post what you tried and explain what you think it should be doing.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah, you're right but I have no idea to implement it unfortunately.

Comment: If you have no idea to the point where you can't even make a basic attempt, then this isn't really the place to seek help.  Do you know how to write SQL queries?  Do you know how to write PHP code?  If you don't, we're not going to teach you.  If you do, then you should be able to at least make a _start_.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using PHP and a query to your database. You will query the database to retrieve a list of Date-times for each registered course for that user.

Once you have the list, you can use PHP code to check if the time and day for the course the user is attempting to register for falls between any of the times in the list from the database.